# Meteor Collection is not displaying

Tags: mongodb, meteor, collections

my meteor collection is not displaying. I can't understand why. I have created my collections and then inserted some records from terminal 
like : 
db.tasks.insert({ text: "Hello world!", createdAt: new Date() });

Here is my code :

**HTML/**

```
<head>
  <title>bdn</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Welcome to Meteor!</h1>
  <ul>
      {{#each tasks}}
        {{text}}
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
</body>

<template name="Tasks">
{{text}}
</template>
```

**MAIN.JS**

```
Tasks = new Mongo.Collection("tasks");

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  // This code only runs on the client
  Template.Tasks.helpers({
    tasks: function () {
      return Tasks.find({});
    }
  });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend avoiding using `<body>` in any of your html files. Meteor takes care of that for you. I'd also recommend making a separate `head.html` file for your head section.

html:

```
<template name="body">
  <h1>Welcome to Meteor!</h1>
  <ul>
      {{#each tasks}}
        {{text}}
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
</template>
```

js:

```
Tasks = new Mongo.Collection("tasks");

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.body.helpers({
    tasks: function () {
      return Tasks.find({});
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: What is the downside of using <body> wrt. a body-template? If I have multiple parts with their own templates you'd get a complicated, nested, body-template.

Comment: Once you start routing (using flow or iron-router) you'll want more reusability of your templates.